# How to retrieve information in a asynchronous manner for push based notifications in MongoDB

Tags: iphone, android, mongodb, push-notification

We are building a service that finds locations of interest (e.g. cafe's, restaurants, hospitals) within a certain radius of a mobile user. Location specific information is stored in MongoDB, so it would be possible for us to fetch all desired locations within a certain radius.

Assuming our application constantly knows about the user location, is there a mechanism to push appropriate locations of interest to the target mobile device?

1. Does MongoDB provide any support to perform async operations on a continuous basis or should this be application specific which actually retrieves relevant information from MongoDB and pushes this information to the mobile device.
2. What kind of push mechanism capabilities are currently available, which can push data in a asynchronous fashion to the mobile device based on his location

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found  such thing in MongoDB but you can do using BlazeDS or ActiveMQ connectors.